# Getting "file not found" error in Swift Bridging Header

Tags: swift, xcode6

Can you help me ?

Since the last week, i'm trying to put the PubNub library inside of my project.

I have my project-Bridging-Header.h

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "PTPusher.h"
#import <PubNub/PNImports.h>
```

Everything is fine when it imports parse, but when it's time to load PTPusher or PubNub/PNImports i got the error "file not found".

I tried call that #import with quotes, "PNImports.h", but the result is the same.

It seems that everything is alright in my Build Settings, anyway, it's still going wrong.

Perhaps somebody who had this same problem in the past can gimme one clue about how to solve it ?

I'm using Xcode 6.1.1

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps your framework search paths aren't searching the right places. I would check that you've added it in the right place in your project files. Or if you haven't tried you could re-add it [manually](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/objective-c/iOS/ios-sdk.html#_where_do_i_get_the_code)

Comment: did you try `#import "PNImports.h"`?

Comment: Yes. I tried these two thing. I've set the search path $(PROJECT_DIR)/MyProject/PubNub, and a lot of more paths, but it doesn't works ! I tried #import "PNImports.h" also, but the result is the same !

Comment: How you resolved this facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

I have same error, I solved it by install older version of PubNub:

```
pod 'PubNub', '3.7.2'
```